# Synergy between ctags and cscope

Tags: c++, ctags, cscope

I've used both cscope and ctags to collectively help browse the C code previously.

Now with C++ code, I'm trying to use them to aid in code browsing. This is how the cscope and ctags DBs have been built:

```
$ find . -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.h' > cscope.files
$ cscope -b
$ ctags -L cscope.files
```

Invoking cscope:

```
$ cscope -d
```

Once I search for a symbol and open the relevant file from within cscope, I'm unable to find definitions of other symbols using . The error is:

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: Parser
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: which editor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the .vimrc file, I found an entry for tags that was pointing to an invalid location. Removing that entry solved the problem.

Thanks!