# VIM : Limit jumplist to certain jump commands

Tags: vim

Vim default behavior for jumplist is as the following

> The following commands are "jump" commands: "'", "`", "G", "/", "?",
>   "n", "N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M",
>   "H" and the commands that start editing a new file.

However, i have the feeling that so many `jump` command make the `jumplist` contain more than what I have. For example, I am using `cscope` to jump to from function invocation to function implementation, then in the implementation, I may use `%` to navigate to matching braces, or `/` to search for certain contents. However, I want the jumplist only keeps the `cscope` jump history so I can easily come back to the invocation point.

Is there some way to exclude certain motion from the `jumplist`?

Comment: I think you want the tag stack, not the jumplist. See `:help tagstack`.

Comment: `tagstack` works when I press `Ctrl+T` or `pop` to go back to previous position. But when I try to use "tag". It prompt me that `E433: no tag file file` and `E426: tag not found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using the regular `ctags` instead of `cscope`, this would be built-in via the [`:help tagstack`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tagstack); the equivalent to `<C-O>` in the jumplist is `<C-T>` in the tagstack.

[`:help cscope-intro`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_cscop.txt.html#cscope-intro) offers the following:

> cscope query results become just like regular tags, so
>   you can jump to them just like you do with normal tags (Ctrl-] or :tag)
>   and then go back by popping off the tagstack with Ctrl-T.  (Please note
>   however, that **you don't actually jump to a cscope tag simply by doing Ctrl-] or :tag without remapping these commands or setting an option**.

Which I think means that, if you use the cscope interface correctly, `<C-T>` should work just fine, but in order to make tag looksups more convenient, you need to build your own shortcuts to the cscope interface.

Comment: the current issue I am meeting is that, with tagstack, it is OK to jump to previous cscope location, but I cannot find a way to jump forward use `tag` command, it prompted me of `no tag file`.
In the cscope help, I still don't quite understand "remapping these commands or setting an option", what is the `option` here?

Comment: I find the solution with the help of [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331992/synergy-between-ctags-and-cscope).

Except to generate the `cscope.out`, need to use `ctags -L cscope.files` to generate the tag entry. With both of that I can now move bidirectionally in `tagstack`

Answer (score 0):

In theory you want to use the tagstack instead of the jumplist as @Ingo Karkat, suggested. However, I think it would be simpler to just use `[[` or `[m` to back to the function definition assuming you didn't leave the function. If you know you are going to come back to it then I would recommend opening a new window (e.g. `:split` or `<c-w>s`) or setting a (file-)mark (e.g. `mm` or `mM`).

Comment: Openning a split window is OK if just jump one layer, however if the function call have several layers, the window will become smaller and smaller and can't display enough code